# Filebeat to kafka - monitoring

Tags: apache-kafka, filebeat

I have filebeat that sends data to kafka.
Could you please tell me, how can I monitor this flow and send allert when no new data in kafka longer than 20 minutes for example.

- do you know some kafka metrics ?
- how can I monitor filebeat directly in the contex above ?

Comment: You can track JMX ingest rates

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 approach for that. The first one is simple and no need to extra effort. It can be useful. So first, you can send data with the timestamp to the topic. And then, look for the last data timestamp in the topic. It will give you some information about timing.
If I need to talk about the second one, of course it's more professional approach than I explained above. But It needs more information about Kafka and Kafka Streams API.
Yes! Apache Kafka Streams! For alerting mechanism, aggregation and something different things is much useful than just consuming. You can use windowing, specifically session windowing going to be the best for your solution.